# Multiline headers in iOS

Tags: ios, header

I'm designing an iOS app with a Q&A section, where every question is its own page. Not every question fits comfortably inside the header.

Should I:

a) put the heading text below the header bar for every question, leaving just a back arrow there

b) do a only for the questions that don't fit

c) decrease font size for those that don't fit (not a fan of this one -- decreases legibility)

d) ellipsize -- the problem there is cutting off a potentially important part of the question

Comment: can you share some screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/navigation-bars/), the correct option is A:

> Consider showing the title of the current view in the navigation bar.
>   In most cases, a title provides context by letting people know what
>   they’re looking at. However, if titling a navigation bar seems
>   redundant, you can leave the title empty. For example, Notes doesn’t
>   title the current note because the first line of content supplies all
>   the context needed.

Certainly not fitting would be a similar case as redundancy. Apple clearly says that it is not required ("**Consider**...") to put the title in the navigation bar; if it's empty the title can come below.

Comment: good answer. Additionally, for a case like the OP's, he could just use titles like "Question 1 of X, Question 2 of X, Final Question" to provide a reference to users

Answer (score 0):

As much as you dislike C, it's the right choice. The choice between reduced legibility and it being unreadable because it doesn't fit only leaves you with one choice, a compromise of reduced legibility, but the complete text.